# Cannot call the protocol method via delegate in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have use one library in Swift [SPSegment](https://github.com/IvanVorobei/SegmentedControl) and I wasn't able to import it to my current project on (Swift)

Is there any ways to import it?

```
class TestMain: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, SPSegmentControlCellStyleDelegate, SPSegmentControlDelegate
```

It gives me an error like:

> Use of undeclared type 'SPSegmentControlDelegate

But it's work fine in sample project

Comment: "I have written library..." are you the writer of library? or you mean that you are using it...?

Comment: how are you not able to use your own library? You should explain how you are currently trying to import it, libraries do not magically get imported when you use a type created by that lib.

Comment: am a user of this library

Comment: i just import a folder in my project and add delegate in class

Comment: @gowtham then I assume that you should `import SPSegmentedControl` in your view controller

Comment: It's not working @AhmadF and sample project never import anything but it's work good how?

Comment: I assumed that you added it as a *pod*, but that's not the case; How you added it to your project?

Comment: @AhmadF Group of Swift files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a reason of problem

> Reason is i can't add SPSegmentedControl in my project target
>   membership in file inspector

[image]

> check project name in Target membership

[image]
it's work fine after i add this

Answer (score 1):

Import that library in your `viewcontroller` and `Build` your project

```
import SPSegmentedControl
```

Comment: No such module 'SPSegmentedControl'

Answer (score 1):

as i saw from the code, it is a sample project that uses Sparrow, you have to use sparrow Folder in your project and it will be ok.

Download [Sparrow](https://github.com/IvanVorobei/Sparrow) and drag and drop extracted folder into your project

the problem is that you can not import SPSegment as a library, becouse if you have a look inside it, it is build as a single project, not as a library. What you can do is to create you project inside SPSegment.
Just add other classes and views, depending in your requests